# How to override a TypeScript UMD global type definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, type-declaration

I have installed `three@^0.103.0`, which has its own type definitions.

In `src/global.d.ts` of my project I have:

```
import * as _THREE from 'three'

declare global {
    const THREE: typeof _THREE
}
```

Then in `src/global.ts` I have

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
(window as any).THREE = { ...THREE }
```

Then in `src/my-code.js` I am trying to use the `THREE` as a global variable, f.e.

```
console.log(new THREE.Vector3(1,2,3)) // ERROR, 'THREE' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

It tells me that `'THREE' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`.

When I jump to the definition of `THREE`, it takes me to `node_modules/three/src/Three.d.ts`, which is not my `src/global.d.ts` file.

So, it seems like TypeScript is ignoring my `global.d.ts` definitions?

My `tsconfig.json` contains

```
  "allowJs" true,
  "checkJs" true,
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
```

and I have `global.d.ts` is inside of `src`.

If I add

```
/// <reference path="./global.d.ts" />
```

to the top of `src/my-code.js` file (JavaScript), then it works, and I can jump to the definition of `THREE` which takes me to my `global.d.ts` file.

Why does it not work without the `reference` comment?

Comment: So, you're overriding the global `THREE`? What reason is there for doing this?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg There is no global THREE; I want to import it into my `global.ts` module and make it a global. But then in my `src/my-code.ts` file I get the error `'THREE' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`. How would I import THREE and make it global in the one module, and use it as a global in the other modules?

Comment: Mohamed Hegazy said "a module (i.e. a file with at least one top-level import ot export) has its own scope, and declarations inside this file are not visible outside it unless exported." over at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21344#issuecomment-361498890. Is this the problem? That I'm importing THREE in a module and declaring a global, and this definition is not visible outside the file (unless I use `reference` for example)? How do I get the definition from `'three'` and make it a global?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I think there's just something wrong with my setup: even if I put nothing but `declare var foo: number` in my `global.d.ts` file, then in any other `.js` file I try `console.log(foo)` and it complains that it can not find `foo`. I think I might just close this question.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Oh, I see the problem. I have both `src/global.ts` and `src/global.d.ts`, which TypeScript apparently merges into one (or something). As soon as I renamed them differently (f.e. `make-global.ts` and `global.d.ts`), then it all started working. I was pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above should work. There's only one small gotcha:

***The two `global` files have the same name!*** (i.e. `global.ts` and `global.d.ts`)

In this case, TypeScript seems to merge them together (or something), and thus seems to treat `global` as the same module (as in `import './global'` being ambiguous).

So, by renaming one module to a different name, it all works.

For example, rename `src/global.ts` to `src/make-global.ts`, and leave `src/global.d.ts`, and it will work.

I was pulling my hair out wondering what was going on until I renamed one of the files.

Comment: You've correctly identified the source of the error, but your solution is unnecessarily complex since you should might as well place all of the code a single file `src/global.ts` file. I go into detail about the subject in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43674912/1915893

Comment: @AluanHaddad Good info there. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For three.js you could declare compiler option `allowUmdGlobalAccess` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,
}
```

This will give typescript access to your project global UMD, where three.js is listed when you install it. Then you could use it at your project same way as for example JQuery.

If this option not available - update your typescript.

[Some details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261279/how-to-declare-reference-to-an-existing-namespace-which-is-available-from-javacr)

Answer (score 2):

You should check TypeScript typings resolution strategy in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules).

As state there, `.ts` files have precedence upon `.d.ts`.

(just bumped into the same problem myself)