# Getting error "TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'global'." with typescript and webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-apps-script

I am trying to set up a project for Google Apps Script with Typescript and Webpack.

I run into an odd error that I don't understand:

> TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'global'

`global` is used by the `gas-webpack-plugin` to create accessible functions in Google Apps Script.

I use it here in my entry point for webpack (`index.ts`):

```
declare let global: any;

global.banana = () => {
  // Method used in Google Apps Script
};
```

I get this error, but I'm not sure where I am redeclaring `global`. I tried excluding `node_modules` from `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}
```

If I add an import before the declare line the error goes away. The content of import doesn't seem to matter. This is what I added. `import { Whatever } from './whatever';`

`whatever.ts` contents:

```
export class Whatever {
  static whatever(): string {
    return "Nothing makes sense";
  }
}
```

Clearly I have a workaround, just wondering why script stops with the error?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between modules and scripts. In a module, all declarations are local to the module and thus do not conflict with any declarations elsewhere. If you want to modify a global variable named global, you can't do it the way your are attempting.

Comment: Just doing a little googling based on your comment. Am I right to say that by adding the import statement I am changing changing the index.ts to a module which changes the variable scope? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/49899979/1915893